# Error en PHP array multibyte

Tags: php, sql-server, array

Saludo, estoy trabajando en `PHP` mostrando algunos cálculos de ciertos elementos, el problema esta que en la base de datos guardaron un dato con tilde y al seleccionarlo me da el siguiente error:

> DETECTED AN INCOMPLETE MULTIBYTE CHARACTER IN INPUT STRING

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: Te recomiendo que normalices esos datos en la base de datos, si no vas a tener que pasarte la vida convirtiendo y reconvirtiendo. Y que revises el código que recibe datos para insertarlos, ahí sí convendría aplicar una conversión de los datos a  `utf8` antes de insertarlos. Dando por supuesto que la tabla y las columnas están configuradas en una codificación similar. Este tipo de problemas hay que resolverlos antes de ingresarlos y en el origen (para los datos ya ingresados), no a medio camino.

Comment: ¿Podrías darnos más datos del problema? ¿Qué versión de PHP usas? ¿Qué sistema operativo? ¿En qué SGBD está guardado el dato? ¿A través de qué función accedes a la base de datos? ¿Qué juegos de caracteres usan la base de datos, tabla y campo? ¿Y el valor por defecto para una conexión?